# Storing key-boolean pairs in AmazonWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store flags (i.e. key-boolean pairs) in noSQL-like storage (e.g. to store information whether a user liked a post). In [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queries#keys-only_queries) keys-only requests (i.e. checking existence of an entity existing by a key but without retrieving it) is much faster and *cheaper*. In [AWS DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/) I haven't found any mentions about key-only (i.e. existence check only) requests with smaller read capacity units cost. Does DynamoDB have it? Or does Amazon WS have better solutions and services for this purpose?